# List item deletion in aura: iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute, aura-iteration

I have a list in which every time I click the "Adicionar outro CID" button a new line with a field and a button "Remover" is added just below it:

**Original image:**

[image]

**After clicking the button:**

[image]

**If I click the button more often, more equal lines are added:**

[image]

**The problem is that when I click on "Remover" a list always excludes a last independent quality line "Remover" I click.
For example, if I click button 1, the third line is removed:**

[image]

**Part of the code that is created when I click on "Adicionar outro CID"**:

```
<lightning:layout multipleRows="true" class="slds-grid_vertical max-1">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.listaCID}" indexVar="index">
              <lightning:layoutItem>
                <c:LookupComponent objectName="CIDs__c" fieldName="Name" campos="Id, Name" campoordenacao="Name"
                  label="CID" labelitalico="(busque pelo nº do CID ou pelo nome da doença)"
                  messageLookup="Mostrar todos os CIDs com essa descrição"
                  placeholder="Digite ao menos 3 iniciais do CID ou nome da doença" />
                  <lightning:button name="{!index}" class="btnAddRemoveCID" title="Remover CID" type="button"
                  label="REMOVER" onclick="{!c.removeCIDsrow}"></lightning:button>     
              </lightning:layoutItem>
            </aura:iteration>
          </lightning:layout>
```

**MY JS**

```
    removeCIDsrow: function (component, event, helper) {
    helper.removeCIDsrow(component, event);

}
```

**MY HELPER**

```
    removeCIDsrow: function (component, event) {
    var newlistaCID = component.get("v.listaCID");

    console.log('new listalenght =>' + newlistaCID.length);
    var toDeletIndex = event.getSource().get("v.name");

    newlistaCID.splice(toDeletIndex, 1);
    component.set("v.listaCID", newlistaCID);
}
```

The variable "toDeletIndex" is returning the correct value of the index I am deleting.

Sorry for the size of the text. Thank you.

Comment: If they all have the same data, how do you know it's the third one being deleted?

Comment: @sfdcfox I use only the index to differentiate them. I'm new to this development part but I suspected that the list items having the same value but differents index values, javascript might not understand which one to exclude, even though I pass the index value, and always delete the last one. Where and how could I add values ​​to differentiate them?

Comment: JavaScript's "splice" deletes the index you specify. As far as I can tell, it looks like it should be doing what you've told it to. I was asking how *you* know it's deleting the third one as opposed to the first. Since they're all identical values, how would you know which row was removed?

Comment: @sfdcfox I use only the index although all values ​​are equal (empty)

Comment: Try entering different values on the input fields, then remove the row. It should be more visually obvious if it's working right.

Comment: @sfdcfox I did this now, but the behavior was that I can not pull elements out of the way. For example: my list has the values ​​1,2,3. By clicking on the "Remover" item "2" nothing happens on the screen. The page is only accepting if I delete it from back to front. Is there a way to render the aura: iteration or something like that?

Comment: @sfdcfox
complementing the previous message, the item is removed from the list. It just does not reflect on the page. 
I believe it's as if he's missing the reference of the one I deleted and thus does not render the page